# Unix sort does not accept the unconventional delimiter '±' as a field separator

Tags: bash, shell, sort, unicode

I tried both

```
... | sort -k'1,1r' -k'2,2' -t'±'

... | sort -k'1,1r' -k'2,2' -t$'\xC2\xB1'


*$> sort: ±: Invalid argument*
```

I hope it is not unsupported by sort, but just that I am missing some escaping or special character handling.

My settings are:

```
localhost:~ user$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

localhost:~ user$ sort --version
2.3-Apple (99)
```

Comment: Can you use `-t$'\xc2'` as a workaround?

Comment: You would need to mention your character encoding and what type of platform you are using. I cannot repeat your problem on a certified UNIX.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release , Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0. I though all shells use utf-8 by default, do they?

Comment: @Freddy no luck but thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you paste the output of `locale` and `sort --version`  into your question?

Comment: Done, thanks @MarkPlotnick

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of Apple macOS `sort`](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/text_cmds), it's little modified from its [FreeBSD origin](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/usr.bin/sort).

In particular, you find the same [awkward/broken handling of the `-t` option as in FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/7474baafb6d06f306b747637efcf4e3e90d013bf/usr.bin/sort/sort.c#L1066).

```
            case 't':
                while (strlen(optarg) > 1) {
                    if (optarg[0] != '\\') {
                        errc(2, EINVAL, "%s", optarg);
                    }
                    optarg += 1;
                    if (*optarg == '0') {
                        *optarg = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

As you can see, the argument to `-t` is accepted only if it's empty (in which case NUL is the delimiter) or contains a single **byte** or starts with any number of `\` characters followed by either a single byte (in which case that byte is taken as the delimiter), or `0` followed by anything, in which case the delimiter is `NUL`.

Examples:

- `-t ''` or `-t '\0'`, or `-t '\\\\\0'` or `-t '\\0whatever` delimits on the NUL character
- `-t '\t'`, `-t '\\\t'` delimits on `t`
- `-t '\'`, `-t '\\\\\'` delimits on  backslash.

In any case, the delimiter can only be a single **byte**, that arcane extra processing is probably only there so `-t '\0'` can be used to specify a NUL delimiter for compatibility with GNU `sort` (FreeBSD's `sort` used to be GNU `sort`), or possibly (since [that commit](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/02feec4a4507f678cfd5036cbb906dcc9908b6ba#diff-ee9ae8de6543f7599e95a8dc8d0ba6e7R1069) which was not even about the `-t` option) so that `-t '\\'` could also be used to specify `\` as the delimiter (not something that GNU `sort` accepts).

So you can't use a multi-byte character as the delimiter.

Not many `sort` implementations allow a multi-byte character there. GNU or busybox `sort` don't either. ast-open's `sort` does though.

Here, you could swap the `±` with a single-byte character (preferably one that is unlikely to occur in the input so it doesn't affect sorting) before sorting and restore afterwards. Thankfully FreeBSD's `tr`, and presumably macOS' `tr` as well supports multi-byte characters (contrary to GNU `tr`):

```
<input tr '±\1' '\1±' | sort -t $'\1' ... | tr '±\1' '\1±'
```

Comment: I found a simplest solution, although this answer is so complete I am not going to add my answer. ```LC_ALL=UTF-8 sort -k'1,1r' -k'2,2' -t$'\xC2'```

Comment: It is truly sad that even in the year 2020, fundamental text processing tools are built on fundamentally broken assumptions that haven't been true in 3-5 decades, if ever.

Comment: @Whimusical, I wouldn't rely on that. 0xC2 is the first byte of characters U+0080 to U+00BF, not just `±`. That also means your second key will start with `\xB1` which means invalid text. Some `strcoll()` implementations will choke on that. It's also possible it would break the day macOS fix their `sort` to support multibyte delimiters.